# How to fail loudly during docker-compose up -d?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using `docker-compose up -d`,  when one of my containers fails to start (i.e. the RUN command exits with an error code), it fails quietly - How can I make it fail loudly?

(Am I thinking about this the right way? My ultimate goal is using Docker for my development environment. I'd like to be able to spin up my environment and be informed of errors right away. I'd like to stay to Docker's true path as much as possible, and am hesitant to depend on additional tools like screen/tmux)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are running it detached (-d), docker-compose only spawns the containers and exits, without monitoring for any issues. If you run the containers in the foreground with:

```
docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
```

That should give you a pretty clear error on any container problems. Otherwise, I'd recommend looking into some of the other more advanced schedulers that monitor the running containers to recover from failures (e.g. Universal Control Plane or Kubernetes).

---

Update: If you want to script something outside of the `docker-compose up -d`, you can do a

`docker events -f "container=${compose_prefix}_" -f "event=die"`

and if anything gets output there, you had a container go down. There's also `docker-compose events | grep "container die"`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just looking for a solution to help teammembers quickly spot container problems in development. Perhaps `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` in a screen/tmux is the answer. Do you know if there are any circumstances under which one could use ^P^Q to later detach from `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`?

Comment: I believe you need to be attached to an interactive terminal for the ^P^Q to work and compose isn't running like that. You can run it in the shell background with `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit >output &`, and then `tail -f output`.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [compose/cli/main.py#L66-L68](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/352cdf0a80d3c2ad2729a3fad300db933d475737/compose/cli/main.py#L66-L68), docker-compose is supposed to fail on (Dockerfile) build:

```
except BuildError as e:
        log.error("Service '%s' failed to build: %s" % (e.service.name, e.reason))
sys.exit(1)
```

Since [`-d` (Detached mode, which runs containers in the background) is incompatible with `--abort-on-container-exit`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/28120148f4e1380096407626f846eda8f6970f36/docs/reference/up.md), a "docker way" would be to:

- wrap the `docker compose up -d` in a script
- add to that script a [`docker-compose logs`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/)), parsing for any error, and loudly exiting if any error message is found..